# How to get json result with unicode character

Tags: c#, json

How can I get the unicode values from json in my coding.

```
string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9789753425988";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string GoogleBook = (wc.DownloadString(url));
GoogleBook = GoogleBook.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
GoogleBookRespons book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleBookRespons>(GoogleBook);
List<BookSearchResult> Results = new List<BookSearchResult>();

public class GoogleBookRespons
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public int totalItems { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }

}

public class BookSearchResult
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Author { get; set; }
    public string Published { get; set; }
    public string Imagelink { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

The displayed result: YÃ¼zÃ¼klerin Efendisi 1 YÃ¼zÃ¼k

But I would like to display it like: Yüzüklerin Efendisi Yüzük

Comment: can you post item and any other classes that item uses as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set WebClient encoding property to UTF-8
like this :

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

and it should work.